# Can I use MotionLayout to animate individual items inside RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-motionlayout

I want to create expandable items, inside a recyclerview, and I thought, using MotionLayout to create the animation would be super easy. I created the motion scene and tested that a single item works on its own when inside a recycler view the view won't animate.

I tried showing all debug info, and it said that the transitions are happening, but the recyclerview did not show any animations. I tried notifying the item animator that animation has started on my viewholder, but that did not work.

```
override fun onTransitionStarted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
  recyclerView.itemAnimator?.onAnimationStarted(this@ViewHolder)
}
override fun onTransitionCompleted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int) {
  recyclerView.itemAnimator?.onAnimationFinished(this@ViewHolder)
}
```

I expected that motinolayout state transitions would work inside recyclerview, but they don't seem to be working.

Single list item:
[image]

Inside list:
[image]

Comment: were you able to keep the MotionLayout and also animating the item resizing? or did you remove it and used the notifyItemChanged() as the answer bellow explains? Wanna know bc Im trying out the expand/collapse animation on my items but same issue

Comment: @Crono I ended up ditching MotionLayout to have expand/collapse. The accepted answer seems good to me. I went with a solution, where I use a `RecyclerView.ListAdapter` and have my adapted objects contain expanded/collapsed information inside them. Then when the user clicked on a list item, the even would cause an emission of a new list, with the list item property change, and through `ListAdapter` magic the changed item would animate without me having to call `notifyItemChanged`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update your ConstraintLayout to `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-rc1` seems this bag was fixed, as well as RecyclerView `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha05`.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to create expandable items, inside a recyclerview, and I thought, using `MotionLayout` to create the animation would be super easy.

Using MotionLayout inside `RecyclerView` for simple expand animation is overkill, you can get the same animation simply by using simple view/hide on the `RecyclerView` `Adapter` `onBindViewHolder`. Then when ever you want to expand/collapse, simply call `notifyItemchanged` with position. That will save your day. cheers!

Inside the RecyclerView Adapter,

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    // Get the current state of the item
    boolean expanded = item.isExpanded();
    // Change the state
    item.setExpanded(!expanded);
    // Notify the adapter that item has changed
    notifyItemChanged(position);
});
```

Comment: It may be one of the best answers on StackOverFlow for Android and RecyclerView.